# $f '$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[-1,1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let f be that function from R to R defined by
f(x)= 0   if   x=0

```
                                         x^2 sin(1/x)  if x not = 0
```

show that the function f' is bot Lebesgue integrable on [-1,1]

Comment: If you want an example of a differentiable function whose derivative is not  integrable, try $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^2)$, $x\ne0$; $f(0)=0$.

Comment: But for sure the last question is Lebesgue?

Comment: Yes. Your exam had a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Is it not hard to see that
$$
f'(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x) & \text{if} & x\ne 0, \\
0 & \text{if} & x=0.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Clearly $f'$ is bounded in $[-1,1]$ and continuous everywhere except at $x=0$.

Hence, not only $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable, but it is Riemann integrable as well!

Note. If $f(x)=x^2\sin (1/x^2)$, for $x\ne 0$, then indeed $f$ is not Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: @Braindead: I corrected it. Indeed, $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable as well!

Comment: but I need to show that f' is not Lebesgue????

Comment: @Jawad where did you get this exercise from?

Comment: It is from a final exam

Comment: @Braindead: See update.